# How to check is unicode char in str in PHP

Tags: php, unicode

I am very new in php and I would know php has function for evaluate specified unicode char exists in another string.

```
$str="Hello world";

echo *function*($str, "e")  //print true

echo *function*($str, "y")  //print false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mb_strpos() or mb_stripos()
look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php

Answer (score 0):

Use strpos for example which find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php

Comment: If you're expecting multibyte strings -- like UTF-8 -- I'd recommend using mb_strpos instead:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php